# NameError: name 'square' is not defined

Tags: python

python初心者です。参考書通りだと思うのですがname 'square' is not definedと出てしまいます

```
"""
Module documentation
words go here
"""
spam=40
def spuare(x):
    """
    function documentation
    can we have your liver then?
    """
    return (x**2)

class employee:
    "class documentation"
    pass
print (square(4))
print (square.__doc__)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "docstrings.py", line 16, in <module>
    print (square(4))
NameError: name 'square' is not defined
```

(Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32)

Comment: `def spuare(x):` となっていますね…

Answer (score 3):

[metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis)さんがコメントされている通り、`def spuare(x):`の箇所で<kbd>q</kbd>と<kbd>p</kbd>をtypoしているようです。

このため、 `spuare` という関数は定義されているものの、 `square` という関数が定義されていないため、 `NameError` が発生しています。

> exception NameError
>   ローカルまたはグローバルの名前が見つからなかった場合に送出されます。これは非修飾の (訳注: spam.egg ではなく単に egg のような) 名前のみに適用されます。関連値は見つからなかった名前を含むエラーメッセージです。
>   [組み込み例外 — Python 3.7.3 ドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/exceptions.html#NameError)